# PURE SQL get days beteen given date and current date, without functions

Tags: mysql, sql, sqldatetime

I need to get number of days between 2 dates, a given one and current date.

But in pure SQL, I mean without usign functions, it is possible?

For exaple

```
SELECT days (t.givenDate) - days (current date) FROM table t
```

Have you any idea?

Thaks a lot.

Comment: `day` is function, probably you're looking for `DATEDIFF`

Comment: You mean like this?

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, current_date(), t.givenDate) FROM dbo.Table t

Comment: yes, note - your syntax is ms sql server, mysql's function does not have 1st argument

Comment: You're right it works like this: SELECT DATEDIFF (current_date(), t.givenDate) FROM dbo.Table t.   Thanks a lot

Comment: mysql syntax does not work in ms sql server, what dbo you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in function is `datediff()`.  The equivalent for the above is:

```
SELECT datediff(t.givenDate, curdate()) FROM table t;
```

Normally, `givenDate` would be in the past and you would want the arguments in the other order.